# ffmpeg combine 2 filters (with lavfi, -vf and -complex_filter)

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay

I have 2 working code's but can't combine them (they both work separately).

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -shortest -t 8 -vf "lutrgb=r=1.5, crop:500:500" output.mp4

ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -f lavfi -i "color=Red:s=1280x720" 
-filter_complex "[0:v]setsar=sar=1/1[s];
[s][1:v]blend=shortest=1:all_mode=overlay:all_opacity=0.7[out]" 
-map [out] -map 0:a output.mp4
```

the lutrgb will be replaced but the color overlay so we can remove that.
endresult will take video, audio, color overlay, crop it to 1:1 and duration length of video.

Thanks
Felix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -f lavfi -i "color=Red:s=500x500" \
-filter_complex "[0:v]lutrgb=r=1.5,crop=500:500,setsar=sar=1/1[crop];\
[crop][2:v]blend=shortest=1:all_mode=overlay:all_opacity=0.7[out]" \
-map [out] -map 1:a -shortest output.mp4
```

Use three inputs:

- `video.mp4` --> 0
- `audio.mp3` --> 1
- `lavfi` --> 2

Chain the filters:

- crop, setsar etc. the video stream in the first input and name it `[crop]`

  `[0:v]lutrgb=r=1.5,crop=320:240,setsar=sar=1/1[crop]`
- blend the video stream of the third input with the crop as `[out]`

  `[crop][2:v]blend=shortest=1:all_mode=overlay:all_opacity=0.7[out]`
- finally map the outputs using out as the video stream and the mp3 track as audio

  `-map [out] -map 1:a`

Comment: thank you very much aergistal. You explanation is very clear. I learn alot from you. It works perfect :)

Comment: Do you know how to get the width and height resolution of -i video.mp4 to use in the crop aspect ratio 1:1 ? Thanks

Comment: It's in the [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) :)  `iw`, `ih` etc.

Comment: sorry :)
but how to do it on 
color=Red:s=iwxiw

it only works on crop=iw:iw

i want to do this
"color=Red:s='if(gt(iw,ih),ih,iw)'x'if(gt(iw,ih),ih,iw)'" to crop it to smallest width or height

Comment: @flieks I think I saw a way to do it, but I dont remember how at the moment. Anyway, I generally make a bash script and use ffprobe to get all the input parameters and then add them as variables in the second command.